# EF4 retrieve many to many with single call

Tags: entity-framework-4

Imagine a simple database where students have multiple courses and multiple exams, given a list of students already loaded from the db, I want to populate the lists of courses and exams with a single database call for each.

I know I can use Include up front which results in a single call to retrieve everything:

```
var students = context.Students.Include("Courses").Include("Exams").ToList();
```

but I also need to be able to load the courses and exams at a later time.

I tried:

```
var courses = students.SelectMany(x => x.Courses).ToList();
var exams = students.SelectMany(x => x.Exams).ToList();
```

but this resulted in two db calls for each student. How can I achieve this more efficiently?

Comment: `ToList()` evaluates and causes the framework to make a call to the database.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that fact. What is your point?

Comment: Just making a comment. Thought you didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you cannot load multiple EntityCollections simultaneously.  You provided the two options in your question.  You can either eagerly load the related entities in a single query or you can load them later via a query for each EntityCollection to load.

Comment: I am happy to have one call per EntityCollection, but option two in my original post results in 2n calls where n is the number of students. so for example, given 100 students, it will make 100 calls to retrieve courses for each student and then another hundred for the exams. There must be a more efficient way than this?

Comment: Ah, I misread your question and didn't realize you were trying to retrieve EntityCollections for a whole set of students.  As far as I am aware, the only efficient way to accomplish this task is to make sure you eagerly load the EntityCollections.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you turn lazy loading off for your entity framework model, IIRC it'll cause those collection properties to fire queries whenever you iterate over them. Otherwise it looks like it should work with just one query.